# Map a join table to a Map object in Java with JPA

Tags: mysql, dictionary, jpa, join

I have five MySQL tables

- `employee`
- `qualification`
- `institute qualification_institute` (id, qualification_id,
  institute_id)
- `employee_qualification_institute` (employee_id, qualification_institute_id)

`qualification_institute` defines a ManyToMany connection between obtainable qualifications and institutes while `employee_qualification_institute` tells us which institute a particular employee got his/her qualification at. EclipseLink generates a `Set<QualificationInstitute>` field in the `Employee` class, however I'd like a `Map<Qualification, Institute>` instead of it. How should I annotate that map? As I have property based access, will I need to implement a query in its getter method?

The `Qualification` class already contains a `Set<Institute>` field while the class `Institute` holds a `Set<Qualification>`. If I could annotate a map inside `Employee`, perhaps I could avoid having to have an explicit `EmployeeQualificationInstitute` class.

Comment: Just to understand...What's the reason for a ManyToManyToMany relationship? Is there the possibility that Employee E has a Qualification Q1 on Institute I1, a Qualification Q2 on Institute I1, a Qualification Q1 on Institute I2 and a Qualification Q2 on Institute I2?? If yes, OK, otherwise this is a bad db design.

Comment: Yes. A certain qualification can be obtained at multiple institutes while each insitute provides multiple qualifications. The Map I need inside the Employee class is to show which qualification was obtained from which institute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you can't. Since by design a qualification isn't unique per institute. And I quote from Map's JavaDoc:

> An object that maps keys to values. A map cannot contain duplicate keys; each key can map to at most one value.

The EmployeeQualificationInstitute class however is not necessary.

Example:

```
@Entity
public class Employee
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    @JoinTable(name="EmployeeQualificationInstitute",
        joinColumns={
            @JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "employee_id")
        }
    )
    private Set<QualificationInstitute>
}

@Entity
public class Qualification
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
}

@Entity
public class Institute
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
}

@Entity
public class QualificationInstitute
{
    @EmbeddedId
    private QualificationInstitutePK key;

    @MapsId(value = "qualification_id")
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "qualification_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Qualification qualification;

    @MapsId(value = "institute_id")
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "institute_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Institute institute;
}

@Embeddable
public class QualificationInstitutePK
{
    @Column(name = "qualification_id")
    private Long qualification_id;

    @Column(name = "institute_id")
    private Long institute_id;
}
```